# Computer Networking - Bit stuffing

Tags: networking

In bit stuffing why always add non information bits after consecutive 5 bits? Any reason behind that?

[image: Bit stuffing image illustration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some information from [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-bit-stuffing-in-computer-networks):

> **Bit-Stuffing**: A pattern of bits of arbitrary length is stuffed in the message to differentiate from the delimiter.

The flag field is some fixed sequence of binary values like 01111110. Now the payload can also have similar pattern, but the machine on the network can get confused and misinterpret that payload data as the flag field (indicating end of frame). So, to avoid the machine getting confused, some bits are stuffed into the payload (especially at points where payload data looks like the flag) so as to differentiate it from flag.

Comment: Thank you.Consider the following data which contains a message that needs to be delivered through a network.                                                                            01001111110111111                                                                                                                               The above data is supposed to be delivered in a bit-oriented synchronous transmission. What is the resulting bit stream after you perform bit stuffing?                   My answer is  **0100111110101111101** am i correct?

Comment: Yes, in data link frame, the delimiter or flag contains 6 or more consecutive 1's. So, at places where you see 6 or more consecutive 1's, put a 0 after the 5th 1. So your answer is correct!